# Run old version from SVN repository, temporarily, without affecting working copy

Tags: c#, svn

I am simulating a model on a set of data. I am continually evolving the simulation and storing sets of result with a note of the SVN Version that created them, which I programmatically to commit prior to each simulation run.

I would like to programmatically run a specific old version at a later date.

Is there an easy way to run/build a previous version without affecting the SVN logs or current Working Copy?

Comment: Not sure, what you are tying to do... You are running a model on a set of data, ok. The model uses the data? Is the model or the data versioned in SVN? What do you commit every time before a new simulation run?

Comment: Data stays the same, only the model changes. I commit all the c# code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just do `svn update -r <xxx>` where *xxx* is the revision where you want to jump to.

It is also possible to specify a time date but I find it easier to first look at the log, then find out the precise revision. Then, **DO NOT** commit (that's what you want to do, but if you want to, read further).

In case that you want to go back to this revision often, you may want to create a branch: `svn cp . <URL of the new branch> -r <xxx>`. Then you can start working in this new branch by checking it out or by switching your current working copy to point to the new branch (in your case I'd suggest checking out).

Then you could *merge* the changes from that revision to the work in the previous branch, but that's another story.

Comment: Hi, no I definitely do not want to go backwards. I only want to run an old version to get some results based on that version's coded logic (data stays the same). I was hoping I could run an old build WITHOUT changing anything in the current working copy.

Comment: I understood you wanted to go backwards to generate a new executable with the old source code. Do you have the old executable version available? Do you store the data in svn? You may reword your question ...